# Profit and loss qn

Tags: arithmetic

The cake shop made a profit of $100/3 \, \%$on every cake sold .
Calculate the selling price of a $1.5$kg strawberry cake if the profit made was $\$5.40$

My workings and thoughts -

I find cost price by --

$100/3 \, \% = \$ 5.40$

$ 100\% = \$ 100$

Selling price = $100+5.40 = \$ 105.40$

Why I can't do the steps like my working above ? And I must find $400/3\, \%$ to find the selling price ? Thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be the selling price. We know that $\frac{100}{3} \% $ of the selling price is $\$ 5.40 $.

So you need to solve the following equation for $x$:
$$ x \cdot \frac{100}{3} \% = \$ 5.40 $$